# Applescript get list of running apps?

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mountain-lion

Applescript newbie question again :) I am trying to create a small applescript that will allow me to select multiple items from a list of currently running applications and then quit those selected apps. Something like this works but rather than having to click on each dialog it would be much easier to chose from a list.

```
tell application "System Events"
repeat with p in every process
    if background only of p is false then
        display dialog "Would you like to quit " & name of p & "?" as string
    end if
end repeat
end tell
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set listOfProcesses to (name of every process where background only is false)
    tell me to set selectedProcesses to choose from list listOfProcesses with multiple selections allowed
end tell
--The variable `selectedProcesses` will contain the list of selected items.
repeat with processName in selectedProcesses
    do shell script "Killall " & quoted form of processName
end repeat
```

Comment: Works like a charm!!! My last question is how would you do this without the killall command? Kind of like, tell application selectedProcesses to quit. Thanks!

Comment: See the bottom part of Parag's script above.

Comment: Edited adding the Parag's script part.

Comment: `killall` by default will send a signal 15 to the process in question, which tells the process to exit as quickly as possible.  It is better practice to send signal HUP, i.e. `killall -HUP`, first, which normally allows the process to do some cleaning up before it shuts down.

Answer (score 6):

```
tell application "System Events"
    set processList to get the name of every process whose background only is false
    set processNameList to choose from list processList with prompt "Select process to quit" with multiple selections allowed
    if the result is not false then
        repeat with processName in processNameList
            do shell script "Killall " & quoted form of processName
        end repeat
    end if
end tell
```

[image]

Comment: The top part of your script did not work for me but the bottom part did! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

you can use this script which is much simpler

```
tell application "Finder"
    get the name of every process whose visible is true
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
tell application "System Events"
        set AppName to name of every process whose background only is false
        choose from list AppName OK button name "Ok" cancel button name "Cancel"
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

`& (name of every process whose (name is "AppName")` can be added to [Michele Percich's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18372603/4322107) and [Parag Bafna's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18373992/4322107) solutions to include specific menu bar applications by name.

`tell application processName to quit` can be used instead of `do shell script "Killall " & quoted form of processName`.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set processList to ¬
        (name of every process where background only is false) & ¬
        (name of every process whose ¬
            (name is "AppName") or ¬
            (name is "AnotherAppName"))
    tell me to set selectedProcesses to choose from list processList with prompt "Select process(es) to quit:" with multiple selections allowed
end tell
if the result is not false then
    repeat with processName in selectedProcesses
         tell application processName to quit
    end repeat
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is pretty straight forward and will gracefully quit the selected *application(s)*, providing the selected *application(s)* is (are) in a stable state:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    set appList to the name of ¬
        every process whose visible is true

set quitAppList to ¬
    choose from list appList ¬
        with multiple selections allowed

repeat with thisApp in quitAppList
    quit application thisApp
end repeat
```

---

When I present a *list* to choose from, I prefer to have it in alphabetical order and to that end I use a *handler* to first sort the list before presenting it:

```applescript
on SortList(thisList)
    set indexList to {}
    set sortedList to {}
    set theCount to (count thisList)
    repeat theCount times
        set lowItem to ""
        repeat with i from 1 to theCount
            if i is not in the indexList then
                set thisItem to item i of thisList as text
                if lowItem is "" then
                    set lowItem to thisItem
                    set lowItemIndex to i
                else if thisItem comes before lowItem then
                    set lowItem to thisItem
                    set lowItemIndex to i
                end if
            end if
        end repeat
        set end of sortedList to lowItem
        set end of indexList to lowItemIndex
    end repeat
    return the sortedList
end SortList
```

To use this with the first *block* of *code* presented I typically add *handlers* at the bottom of my *code* and then to use it, add the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* between the `tell application "Finder" to ¬` and `set quitAppList to ¬` *statements*:

```applescript
set appList to SortList(appList)
```

---

<sub>Note: I acquired this particular *handler* somewhere on the **Internet** too many years ago to remember and unfortunately lost who to credit it to. My apologies to whomever you are.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this following AppleScript code a few years back.  I consider it to be a “Must Have” because I use it almost every single day.

This code will generate a list of Visible and Hidden application processes, allowing multiple items to be selected to kill their processes.  The first items in the list will be visible application processes (not sorted alphabetically), then an empty list item (used to separate the visible from the hidden processes), and the remaining list items will be the hidden application processes (sorted alphabetically)

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

property appsToKill : missing value
property NSArray : a reference to current application's NSArray

listAllAppProcesses()

activate
set killApp to (choose from list ¬
    appsToKill with title "Choose The App To Kill" with prompt ¬
    "Choose The App/Apps To Kill" & linefeed & linefeed ¬
    & "The Empty List Item Separates The Visible From The Hidden Applications" OK button name ¬
    "OK" cancel button name "CANCEL" with multiple selections allowed)

set pidList to {}

if killApp is not false then
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with i from 1 to count of killApp
            set thisItem to item i of killApp
            tell application process thisItem
                set thePID to unix id
                set end of pidList to thePID
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
else
    return
end if

set text item delimiters to space
do shell script ({"kill -9", pidList} as text)

on listAllAppProcesses()
    tell application "System Events"
        set visibleAppsToKill to name of every application process ¬
            where visible is true
        set invisibleAppsToKill to name of every application process ¬
            where visible is false
        set aList to ((NSArray's arrayWithArray:invisibleAppsToKill)'s ¬
            sortedArrayUsingSelector:"caseInsensitiveCompare:") as list
        set appsToKill to visibleAppsToKill & "" & aList
    end tell
end listAllAppProcesses
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want it from Terminal, you can use a simple script like this [quit.rb](https://gist.github.com/3a1d4e221047888446dd7ebeaeebfdfa)