# Is there a way to get all applications running using the "whose" keyword?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to figure out how to use the whose keyword in applescript. But google doesn't seem to have any reference. I try to use this code:

```
set open_applications to get application whose running is true
```

I tried using reference from another stack overflow question but I don't want to test if an application is open with any interaction. I also checked google. Please help me solve this problem!

Comment: This is a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372328/applescript-get-list-of-running-apps].  Just don’t use the part of that script that requests user input.   Also, “whose clause” is a synonym for “where” and “that”.

Comment: Oh, thanks! That answer helped me a lot. But I don't understand how it works...

Comment: It is a [filter reference form](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_reference_forms.html) - note that it only applies to application objects.

Answer (score 0):

"All applications" is a vague term, as it potentially refers to every running process, which I don't think you want; or limits to applications with interactive UIs, or visible apps; or perhaps specifically refers, in an AppleScript context, to running applications that are scriptable.

I've interpreted it as a desire for a list of applications that is practical and omits system applications of which one usually isn't aware.  And, by this, I'm basically interested in apps that live in the `/Applications` folder:

```
tell application "System Events" to get the name of every process ¬
    where its application file's POSIX path starts with ("/Applications") ¬
    and its application file's name extension = ("app")
```

<sup>**NB:** The parentheses around the quoted strings aren't syntactical; they only help preserve multi-line formatting in *Script Editor* and *Script Debugger*.</sup>

This returns application names you'll recognise, but doesn't include familiar system apps that reside in `~/Library` or `/Library`, including *Finder* or *System Events*.

If you need a different sort of application list, feel free to clarify your specific needs (or describe what you will be using the list for, which might actually be a more useful detail), and I can add to this answer.